# Can someone explain how i can just call for ridgedbody2d with this code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I have a script calling from another class, I'm wondering how I can write this to only destroy the ridgedbody 2d. I know that it will keep the sprite in scene which is what I'm looking for.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)      
{
     DamageDealer damageDealer = other.gameObject.GetComponent<DamageDealer>();
     health -= damageDealer.GetDamage();
}
```

Comment: Use `Object.Destroy`: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in a `Component` reference to [`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) it will only destroy the according component but keep the rest of the `GameObject` untouched

> The object obj will be destroyed now or if a time is specified t seconds from now. **If obj is a `Component` it will remove the component from the `GameObject` and destroy it**. If obj is a `GameObject` it will destroy the `GameObject`, all its components and all transform children of the `GameObject`.

```
Destroy(damageDealer.GetComponnet<Rigidbody2D>());
```

---

If you do this quite often it might be better to store this reference already in `Awake` of the `DamageDealer` component and later pass it on like

```
public class DamageDealer : MonoBehaviour
{
    // if possible already reference this via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

    // This is a read-only property returning the value of rigidbody
    public Rigidbody2D Rigidbody => rigidbody;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!rigidbody) rigidbody = GetComponnet<Rigidbody2D>();

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

then later you can simply do

```
Destroy(damageDealer.Rigidbody);
```